# Create a SQL query with conditions from a radio button and radio button list ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I am currently using Visual Studio 2015. Right now, I am able to connect to the Database using SqlConnection and show the data in a gridview. This code is in the Result page.

```
private void BindGrid()
    {
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            if (Interface_trial_1.RadioButtonList1.Checked == true)
            { 
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Emp]"))
            {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                            GridView1.DataBind();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

However, I do not know how to run a query with conditions from a radio button and a radio button list in the Index page. In addition, I have no clue on how to transfer the value of a radio button or a radio button list from the Index page to the Result page.

Would it be better if I were to run the query in the Index page and show the data in the Result page or transfer the values from the Index page and run the query in the Result page?

Please advice. I am in need of guidance. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use various [ASP.NET state management techniques](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx) to pass data between pages.For example you could use query strings to collect the data entered in the `RadioButton` and `RadioButtonList` on the **Index** page and pass it through to the **Result** page.

**Index page:**

```
protected void btnOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isHungry = rdbHungry.Checked;
    string menuItem = rdbMenu.SelectedItem.Text;

    string url = String.Format("Result.aspx?isHungry={0}&menuItem={1}", isHungry, menuItem);
    Response.Redirect(url);
}
```

**Result page:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool isHungry = Boolean.Parse(Request.QueryString["isHungry"]);
    string menuItem = Request.QueryString["menuItem"].ToString();
    //Write your SQL query here and make sure you check the parameters to prevent SQL injection attacks
}
```

Comment: The user has to select the button and I have about 6 buttons with 1 sub button. So how do you allow the code to know which button is selected and transfer it over to the Result page?

Comment: Use command buttons - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.command(v=vs.110).aspx.Specify the CommandName property of each button and assign the same OnCommand event to all buttons -> then in the OnCommand event evaluate the e.CommandName property to find out which button was clicked

Comment: the link you sent me showed "We're Sorry, the page you requested cannot be found"

Comment: Try this link - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.command(v=vs.110).aspx or just search "ASP.NET command buttons" there are thousands of articles on the web about this